# Does anyone know about the Visual Studio 2019 C++ MFC Resource Editor? I get 0x80004005 (Unspecified Error) when I try to open the IDR_MAINFRAME menu

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I am withdrawing this post because I have found that I sometimes have the same error code when opening other files. 0x80004005 "Unspecified Error". Thanks you for your responses.

"Does anyone know about the Visual Studio 2019 C++ MFC Resource Editor? I get 0x80004005 (Unspecified Error) when I try to open the IDR_MAINFRAME menu"

Comment: You should be more specific. Code 8827 says nothing. What is the message associated with such code? And you do not provide us any source or screen shots. If you want to be  help, you have to make a clearer picture of your issues. You don't go to a doctor and simply say you are ill. You provide the doctor with the information he/she needs to cure you.

Comment: *"it reports to be corrupted"* - That does not make sense. A document is just a document. It has no behavior. Something else must be reporting that error, some program, executable code. You'll have to be specific about the program that reports the error, under which conditions, and what the error is. Resource files are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files).

Comment: FWIW, I just created a resource file with a 500-item menu; opens OK in Resource Editor.

Comment: You could try opening the resource.h file with ResOrg and see if it reports any errors or duplicates.

Comment: @David F would it be possible to share this file?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I should have provided more info. I am editing the post. Thanks